# Webscraping with Nokogiri - a specific example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

Looking for help to get me started. I am trying to scrape the latest game information from this website:

https://www.pinnacle.com/en/odds/match/soccer/england/england-premier-league

I am really struggling with the syntax to use to pull the code out using Nokogiri. All the examples I have seen and tried all use much simpler sites than this!

So if I have:

```
class BdcController < ApplicationController

def bdc
    require 'nokogiri'

    require 'openssl'

    doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(open('https://www.pinnacle.com/en/odds/match/soccer/england/england-premier-league?sport=True', :ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE))

    hometeam = doc.css('table.odds-data.game-name name').text #no idea what this line shoudl be to return e.g the first team in the list (currently Leicester City)

end

@grab=hometeam

end
```

it currently returns nil (not surprising as I can't work out what the home team line should look like!)

Could someone give me an example of what that line starting home team should read? Thanks in advance!

TD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, I use [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to extract HTML first and then pass it on to Nokogiri

```
url = "https://www.pinnacle.com/en/odds/match/soccer/england/england-premier-league?sport=True"
html = HTTParty.get(url, verify: false).body
parser = Nokogiri::HTML(html, nil, Encoding::UTF_8.to_s)
parser.css('table.odds-data>tbody>tr>td.game-name>span').text
```

Output

```
"{{participant.Name}}{{'Draw' | guestlinesDraw}}{{participant.Pitcher}}"
```

By the way looking at the source code, it does not have what you are looking for directly. It's being interpolated by Javascript.

If you want to scrape such text, you should go for selenium web driver and use a different strategy to attack this problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help - I think your last point is the problem. I want it to output 'Leicester City' in that example but that isnt in the source code grabbed by HTTPParty. I will look up selenium....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that website is using angular, so its HTMLS response is like this:

```
 <td class="game-name name">
    <span ng-if="participant.Name != undefined">{{participant.Name}}</span>
    <span ng-if="participant.IsDraw == true">{{'Draw' | guestlinesDraw}}</span>
    <span ng-if="participant.IsDraw == false && !!participant.Pitcher" class="pitcher">{{participant.Pitcher}}</span>
</td>
```

Like that you can't get the value retrieved from those libraries. You're gonna have to use some one that emulates a web browser, so it really renders the content from angular and you can get the real value from those variables. It's not quite simple, anyway. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks - that's the conclusion I was coming to although without understanding whether it was just me not understanding it or the actual way the website worked. Will start looking at angular - although it's probably too difficult!!